# How to create an elasticbeanstalk environment through boto3 setting a keypair name

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, cloud, boto3

If you uses the AWS console or even the command line, you won't get any issue in setting a default keypair to your Elasticbeanstalk environment.

But you do if using boto3.

Surprisingly, there's no any single mention about setting a keypair in the official boto3 documentation for elasticbeanstalk: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/elasticbeanstalk.html.

Tried also to create a zip file containing the most basic files to make a simple website works. And supposedly, I can set a keypair name in the `.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml`". I did in this way:

```
branch-defaults:
  default:
    environment: app10-env
    group_suffix: null
global:
  application_name: app10
  branch: null
  default_ec2_keyname: main4
  default_platform: PHP 7.4 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2
  default_region: us-east-1
  include_git_submodules: true
  instance_profile: null
  platform_name: null
  platform_version: null
  profile: null
  repository: null
  sc: null
  workspace_type: null
```

Yes, the "`main4`" exists in my AWS account. But creating an environment to my application with a zip containing it, it seems that it have no effect at all. After my environment has sucessfully deployed, I can check afterwards through console and see that have no keypair setted to environment. I need to go to a further step on console to set the keypair and await a new environment deployiment to perform the update.

Is there a real issue with the boto3 elasticbeanstalk when dealing with environment keypairs or I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I would set the OptionSettings when calling `create_environment` or include the keyname in the `.ebextensions`. Boto3 is not reading the EB CLI default config you are using i guess.

#### Refs

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/elasticbeanstalk.html#ElasticBeanstalk.Client.create_environment

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-configuration-methods-before.html

#### Option to set

- Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
- Option Names: IamInstanceProfile, EC2KeyName, InstanceType

Answer (score 1):

The response of @f7o is not accurate, but helped to solve the problem.

There's no option for setting an keypair using "`create_environment`" command from boto3 client. Tried to use a "`EC2KeyName`", but it returned an exception of invalid value.

But using the "`ebextensions`" do the work. If someone else are interested in do the same task that I am, so everything that is needed to do is create a folder called "`.ebextensions`" with a file called "`customkey.config`" (the file name can be anything, but must be suffixed with `.config`), and with the following content:

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
    option_name: EC2KeyName
    value: <your_keypair_name>
```